# How can I log SQL statements in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, logging

I want to log SQL statements to a file.

I have the following properties in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

security.ignored=true
security.basic.enabled=false

logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
logging.file=c:/temp/my-log/app.log
```

When I run my application,

```
cmd> mvn spring-boot:run
```

I can see SQL statements in the console, but they don't appear in *app.log*. The file contains only basic logs from Spring.

What should I do to see SQL statements in the log file?

Comment: Follow instructions on https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Answer (score 662, accepted):

Try using this in your properties file:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Comment: If you want to log values too: `logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE`

Comment: But this logs only few bind values. How can I log values from the criteria-API? If I use Specifications, I get no output for bound parameters created with the CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: What about people that use `EclipseLink` instead of `Hibernate` ?

Comment: @payne post a separate question

Comment: In my project using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.1.4 and hibernate 6.2.9, the "logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE" did not work to show the values. I had to change it to "logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE"

Answer (score 311):

This works for standard output too:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

To log values:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

Just add this to `application.properties`.

Comment: If you want to log values too: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace`

Comment: This doesn't write to log file, this writes to STDOUT

Comment: I still see only `?` instead of the parameters. Was that solution supposed to show them to me?

Comment: @Adeynack Sorry I can't help you. I just added it according _elysch's_ words.

Comment: @v.ladynev: But does it shows the parameters' value to you or does it shows question marks?

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace doesn't affect my log file ;(

Comment: The "type=trace" is not a spring property, so it does not work. The solution given out below https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594913/5107365 is the right one for that.

Comment: @Raj Thank you very much. I have updated the answer.

Comment: What about people that use `EclipseLink` instead of `Hibernate` ?

Comment: This works for me, I'm using spring boot 2.5.9

Comment: We can even have syntax highlighting via ANSI escape codes:
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.highlight_sql=true`

Answer (score 160):

This works for me ([YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)):

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        type: trace
```

Comment: I always thought that `show_sql: true` belongs to `jpa`

Comment: You are right, it should be in jpa section

Answer (score 151):

### Settings to avoid

You should not use this setting:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The problem with `show-sql` is that the SQL statements are printed in the console, so there is no way to filter them, as you'd normally do with a Logging framework.

### Using Hibernate logging

In your log configuration file, if you add the following logger:

```xml
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug"/>
```

Then, Hibernate will print the SQL statements when the JDBC `PreparedStatement` is created. That's why the statement will be logged using parameter placeholders:

```sql
INSERT INTO post (title, version, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

If you want to log the bind parameter values, just add the following logger as well:

```xml
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="trace"/>
```

Once you set the `BasicBinder` logger, you will see that the bind parameter values are logged as well:

```
DEBUG [main]: o.h.SQL - insert into post (title, version, id) values (?, ?, ?)
TRACE [main]: o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [High-Performance Java Persistence, part 1]
TRACE [main]: o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [0]
TRACE [main]: o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

### Using datasource-proxy

The [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) OSS framework allows you to proxy the actual JDBC `DataSource`, as illustrated by the following diagram:

[image: DataSource-Proxy]

You can define the `dataSource` bean that will be used by Hibernate as follows:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(DataSource actualDataSource) {
    SLF4JQueryLoggingListener loggingListener = new SLF4JQueryLoggingListener();
    loggingListener.setQueryLogEntryCreator(new InlineQueryLogEntryCreator());
    return ProxyDataSourceBuilder
        .create(actualDataSource)
        .name(DATA_SOURCE_PROXY_NAME)
        .listener(loggingListener)
        .build();
}
```

Notice that the `actualDataSource` must be the `DataSource` defined by the [connection pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c67Gb.png) you are using in your application.

Next, you need to set the `net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener` log level to `debug` in your logging framework configuration file. For instance, if you're using Logback, you can add the following logger:

```xml
<logger name="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener" level="debug"/>
```

Once you enable `datasource-proxy`, the SQL statement are going to be logged as follows:

```
Name:DATA_SOURCE_PROXY, Time:6, Success:True,
Type:Prepared, Batch:True, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:3,
Query:["insert into post (title, version, id) values (?, ?, ?)"],
Params:[(Post no. 0, 0, 0), (Post no. 1, 0, 1), (Post no. 2, 0, 2)]
```

Comment: What exactly does to enable the `datasource-proxy` means here? Is it another configuration? Is there something extra that needs configuration apart from creating the bean with the proper datasource? Do we also need to configure something in the log4j.properties at this point?

Comment: I updated the answer to answer your questions.

Comment: It do not work,how does Hibernate know to use this bean?

Answer (score 29):

Please use:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 26):

If you have a `logback-spring.xml` file or something like that, add the following code to it:

```xml
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</logger>
```

That works for me.

To get bind variables as well:

```xml
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</logger>
```

Comment: With Spring Boot you have to use `<appender-ref ref="FILE" />`

Comment: appender ref is the name of the appender that you have defined in the logback xml. It is only a variable

Answer (score 15):

For the [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) driver (Microsoft SQL Server [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) Driver), try using:

```
logging.level.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc=debug
```

in your application.properties file.

My personal preference is to set:

```
logging.level.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc=info
logging.level.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals=debug
```

You can look at these links for reference:

- *[Tracing driver operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/tracing-driver-operation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)*
- *[“How-to” Guides, 7. Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging)*

Answer (score 14):

For hibernate 6:
it is:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind = trace
```

Comment: I verified this for Spring Boot 3.0.0, which uses hibernate 6.1.5. Though, for me, I used `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` and `logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE`.

Answer (score 13):

Translated accepted answer to YAML works for me

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL:
          TRACE
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder:
                TRACE
```

Comment: You can also use flat properties in YAML if you don't want to nest for single use props, like:

`logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: TRACE`
`logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE`

Answer (score 11):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) it is:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true # Enable logging of SQL statements.
```

Comment: I have reverse problem, setting this to false, and org.hibernate to level ERROR and its still printing drop/create/insert/select

Answer (score 11):

## **Log in to standard output**

Add to `application.properties`

```
### To enable
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

### To make the printing SQL beautify
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

This is the simplest way to print the SQL queries, though it doesn't log the parameters of prepared statements.

And it’s not recommended since it’s not such as optimized logging framework.

#### Using a logging framework

Add to `application.properties`

```
### Logs the SQL queries
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
### Logs the prepared statement parameters
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

### To make the printing SQL beautify
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

By specifying the above properties, log entries will be sent to the configured log appender, such as log-back or [Log4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j).

Answer (score 9):

We can log SQL statements using two approaches in Spring boot:
1: using logger
2: standard approach

---

**For logger**
You should add this line to application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

---

**Standard Approach**
You should add these lines in application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: This standard approach only works for console log.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve that problem by adding these variables lines in **application.properties** file:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

That made me able to see debugging SQL queries (in formatted shape) and the passed variables (parameters) values.

And my log output was like this:

```
17:21:45.965 [http-nio-7001-exec-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        a1_0.action_id,
        a1_0.action_nr,
        a1_0.app_version
    from
        action a1_0 
    where
        a1_0.guid=? limit ?
17:21:45.965 [http-nio-7001-exec-5] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [60154cd5-3f51-4c45-9c65-2af724c5c693]
17:21:45.965 [http-nio-7001-exec-5] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

Comment: I can confirm it works with SpringBoot 3!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to view the actual parameters used to query you can use

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=TRACE
```

Then notice that actual parameter value is shown as `binding parameter`...:

```
    2018-08-07 14:14:36.079 DEBUG 44804 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select employee0_.id as id1_0_, employee0_.department as departme2_0_, employee0_.joining_date as joining_3_0_, employee0_.name as name4_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.joining_date=?
     2018-08-07 14:14:36.079 TRACE 44804 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Aug 07 00:00:00 SGT 2018]
```

Answer (score 7):

We can use any one of these in the *application.properties* file:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Example:

```
//Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_0_, country0_.name as name2_0_ from country country0_
```

or

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Example:

```
2018-11-23 12:28:02.990 DEBUG 12972 --- [nio-8086-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL   : select country0_.id as id1_0_, country0_.name as name2_0_ from country country0_
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this code in the file *application.properties*:

```
# Enable logging for configuration troubleshooting
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add the below lines in application.properties for stdout SQL queries:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Comment: What are *"stdout SQL queries"*? *"standard out SQL queries"*? Can you elaborate? Or do you mean *"standard SQL queries"*?

Comment: By stdout queries, I mean to say that the queries which are further generated by JPA that are going to run over our DB can be logged over console or log files.

Answer (score 3):

Putting `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true` in application.properties didn't help always.

You can try to add `properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");` to the properties of the database configuration.

```
public class DbConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.test.dbsource.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("dbsource").properties(properties)
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in *application.properties*.

For example, you may refer to *[ConfigServerRepo/application.yaml](https://github.com/007anwar/ConfigServerRepo/blob/master/application.yaml)*.

Answer (score 3):

In my YAML file:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql: TRACE
```

Spring Boot version: 2.3.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble with this setting and it seems to work sometimes and not other times - consider if the times where it doesn't work are during unit tests.

Many people declare custom test-time properties via the `@TestPropertySources` annotation declared somewhere in your test inheritance hierarchy.  This will override whatever you put in your `application.properties` or other production properties settings so those values you're setting are effectively being ignored at test-time.

Answer (score 2):

The basic way is to add the following lines in your `application.properties`. This will enable Spring Boot to log all your SQL queries that get executed:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

The second line is used to beautify the SQL statements.

If you want to use loggers, you can use the following lines:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

The second line is used to print all the parameters that get bound with your queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
```

has been renamed to:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these in the properties. Quoting [Hibernate Show SQL](https://springframework.guru/hibernate-show-sql/):

```
# Show SQL statement
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

# Show SQL values
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JdbcTemplate, add the below in `application.properties` file to log SQL and parameter values.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE
```