# Hibernate connects to Postgres db but it doesn't retrieve data

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a Java web application and I'm trying to retrieve a list of Clients from a Postgres database via class configured Hibernate. As far as I can tell, the application does get the connection because I checked the metadata from the connection and I see all my tables in there so it's alright. The problem is that I don't get any data from the table.

Here is my model for the Client:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Client")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable= false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="age", nullable = false)
    private Integer age;

    @Column(name="numberofrentals", nullable = false)
    private Integer numberofrentals;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="address", nullable = false)
    private String address;

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(Integer id, Integer age, Integer numberofrentals, String name, String address) {

        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.numberofrentals = numberofrentals;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Integer getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getnumberofrentals() {
        return numberofrentals;
    }

    public void setnumberofrentals(int numberofrentals) {
        this.numberofrentals = numberofrentals;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Client client = (Client) o;

        if (age != client.age) return false;
        if (numberofrentals != client.numberofrentals) return false;
        if (!id.equals(client.id)) return false;
        if (!name.equals(client.name)) return false;
        return address.equals(client.address);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age;
        result = 31 * result + numberofrentals;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + address.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", numberofrentals=" + numberofrentals +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the JPAConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
public class JPAConfig {

    //    @Value("${db.jdbcURL}")
    private String jdbcURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Shop";

    //    @Value("${db.user}")
    private String user = "postgres";

    //    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password = "*****";

    //    @Value("${db.generateDDL}")
    private Boolean generateDDL = true;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        PGPoolingDataSource dataSource = new PGPoolingDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setUrl(jdbcURL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dataSource.setUser(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setMaxConnections(4);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(generateDDL);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        GuavaCacheManager guavaCacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager();
        guavaCacheManager.setCacheBuilder(CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(2, TimeUnit.HOURS));
        return guavaCacheManager;
    }
}
```

I get connected but no data from my Client table which has these exact same fields: id(PK), age, numberofrentals, name, address. Any ideas what's wrong? I'm using the findall() from the JpaRepository. I don't understand what could be the problem, everything seems to be right.

If there's more code necessary, I can post more.

Is there any way to debug this or find out what is wrong because so far I could only get the connection and the list of tables and the rest of information sounds alright?
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Print the SQL logs and try the SQL commands against the database manually. [how to log sql statements in spring-boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot).

Comment: i think you'll need the dialect of the database

Comment: Yea, that's more of a problem. I am using postgres and I'm not sure at all what the spirng boot would do. I checked the connectiong though... it's there. It sees my tables, it even creates table if they don't exist. It just refuses to read anything from them via Jpa

Answer (score 0):

When hibernate creates a table, for some reason it creates it with all lower case letters and it will also read from those. I thought it accesses case-sensitive so I was adding data into the wrong table tables whereas the correct ones remained always empty.