# Why is spring jpa creating column marked 'unique' in a related table?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have a Spring Boot app using Spring JPA, hibernate, Derby database, having the following entities and relationships;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Profile
    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="profile_id")
    private Profile profile;

    // ... other fields + getters & setters 
}
```

And then I have a related Entity shown below;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
public class Profile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to User
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="profile")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastname;

    // ... other fields + getters & setters 
}
```

Strangely, I noticed that when I run the application and the Database tables get created from the Entities, an **email** Column also gets created in the **profiles** Table, even though the Entity has no **email** field declared.

**1.** Can someone please first of all explain why this is happening?

**2.** How do I ensure that the **profiles** Table does not have an **email** Column?

Comment: Please, enable SQL log and add SQL create table commands.

Comment: I've tried both `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true` in my **application.properties** file, but none of them shows the SQL queries that are executed when the database Tables are being created from the Entiities...

Comment: Please, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31249985/3405171

Comment: And, please, check that `application.properties` in the class path. It should be in the root of your build folder. For Eclipse it can be `bin` or `build`.

Comment: application.properties is placed correctly in the root... all other properties set in the file are are currently being read appropriately and utilized.... However I will try the suggestion in that link you've provided and see what happens