# Spring jpa native query throws MySQLSyntaxErrorException when having 0 results

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I need bit masking MySQL query in Spring JPA Specification. I is not supported by default, so I am trying to combine native query with it. Sometimes I am getting MySQLSyntaxErrorException, that is not catchable. It seems to be thrown when there is 0 results in the database.
The query (when defined on Repository) is

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM xx_user_group WHERE (role_flagval&?1)<>0", nativeQuery = true)
```

or (another method)

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM user_group WHERE (role_flagval&"+val+")<>0", UserGroup.class)
```

I have results without problems, but they they arrises when there is no record in the DB. Testing through DB returns zero results.

- **Is there a way how to hack bit masking in Spring JPA?**
- **... or catch the MySQLSyntaxErrorException?**

Thank you all. Here is complete error stacktrace (only when DB has no result):

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206) ~[websocket-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-security-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317) ~[jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110) [jetty-io-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128) [jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222) [jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294) [jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) [jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672) ~[jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590) ~[jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar:9.4.4.v20170414]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at hello.controller.TestController.bitewise(TestController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:398) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
... 104 common frames omitted
```

In log I found two queries. One written by me, and another, maybe causing the error:

```
2017-06-28 17:43:08.561 DEBUG 5228 --- [  qtp4609951-18] org.hibernate.SQL                        : SELECT * FROM xx_user_group WHERE (role_flagval&4)<>0
2017-06-28 17:43:08.564 DEBUG 5228 --- [  qtp4609951-18] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select xxusergrou0_.`id` as id1_4_, xxusergrou0_.`group_id` as group_id2_4_, xxusergrou0_.`role_flagval` as role_fla3_4_, xxusergrou0_.`user_id` as user_id4_4_ from `xx_user_group` xxusergrou0_ where xxusergrou0_.`role_flagval` in ()
2017-06-28 17:43:08.567  WARN 5228 --- [  qtp4609951-18] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2017-06-28 17:43:08.568 ERROR 5228 --- [  qtp4609951-18] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

[logging for db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot)

According to log there is an error caused by another query, that has empty `in()` statement.

Comment: Could you post the complete error stack trace?. Furthermore do **not** use `(role_flagval&"+val+")`. Use the `setParameter` chained after `createNativeQuery` instead

Comment: Post more code, the code shown here doesn't contain anything that will break. I guess you are doing a `getSingelResult` or are returning a single element from the query. Which indeed will throw an error if nothing is there (as a single record is to be expected). If that isn't what you want return a List instead.

Comment: My aim is to get all records having at least one masked bit. After this query I would make a list of flagvals for specification where  `query.where(root.get(field).in(listOfFlagvals))`.

Comment: @ManuelJordan: Your advice looked good, can avoid problems with parameter. Throws the error though.
`entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM user_group WHERE (role_flagval&?1)<>0", UserGroup.class).setParameter(1, val)`
IMHO it is the same as my first way of usage - parametric.

Comment: @JTV could you post the complete repository methods?. Mostly the second. Once resolved that the first should be more easier

Answer (score 0):

you can write query link this :

```
SELECT * FROM table_laef WHERE id = ? AND genre_type <> 'LIVE'
```

for more refer bellow link :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-traditional

Answer (score 0):

can you please check the value that your are passing to the method?

As in the exception stack it states that MySQLSyntaxErrorException because of 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1'

Actually what is happening here is on run time the query is resolved as :

"SELECT * FROM xx_user_group WHERE (role_flagval&)<>0"

Because of that its giving exception. Can you do a basic analysis like what value you are sending?

Comment: Thank you, that was important. The error is not connected to this query but to another, that should use product of this and obtains blank list. I added log into post.