# See query generated with spring data - jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I done a git clone of spring data - jpa.

I search a way when I running test to see generated query.

Comment: [See this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot)

Comment: good try but it's for spring boot... so no really working for spring-data....

Comment: You just need to set the hibernate properties and the log level of your specific logging framework, same principle applies. The loggers you want turned on are:
`org.hibernate.type=TRACE` for bind values
`org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` for SQL
You can also set the property 
`hibernate.show_sql=true`
All depends on how you configuring the session factory in spring data.

Comment: Found the answer here as the accepted answer didnt work in my application.yml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-can-i-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with the followings:

- Edit the `/src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` file and add the following two lines in the `<properties>` section of `cdi`, `cdi-52`, `merchant`,  `metadata`  and `metadata-52` persistence-unit.

  ```
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  ```
- Add the below line in the `<properties>` section of the same file's persistent-unit named `metadata_oj`

  ```
  <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=Trace" />
  ```
- Edit the `src/test/resources/eclipselink.xml` file and rewrite below section as :

  ```
  <util:properties id="jpaProperties">
      <prop key="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</prop>
      <prop key="javax.persistence.jdbc.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:hades</prop>
      <prop key="javax.persistence.jdbc.user">sa</prop>
      <prop key="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"></prop>
      <prop key="javax.persistence.ddl-generation">create-tables</prop>

      <prop key="eclipselink.logging.level.sql">FINE</prop>
      <prop key="eclipselink.logging.parameters">true</prop>
  </util:properties>
  ```
- Also, edit the below section of `src/test/resources/openjpa.xml` file as:

  ```
  <util:properties id="jpaProperties">
      <prop key="openjpa.Log">SQL=Trace</prop>
  </util:properties>
  ```

Then, you can run `mvn test` to test the project and check whether you can see the generated queries or not.