# Java Spring Hibernate Saving Duplicate Values to MySQL table is throwing error

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hibernate

I am trying to save some values to a MYSQL database using CrudRepository but doesnt seem to work. I have tried the following guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ and it works fine but when iam trying to follow the same principle for my program it doesnt seem to work for some reason.

Here is the class iam creating a database for, The table gets created properly:

```
 @Entity
 public class MeasurementPoint {

 @Id


 @JsonProperty("f1")
 private double f1;

 @JsonProperty("precison")
 private double precison;

 @JsonProperty("recall")
 private double recall;

 private String date;

 public MeasurementPoint(double f1, double precison, double recall, String 
 date)  {
     this.f1 = f1;
     this.precison = precison;
     this.recall = recall;
     this.date=date;
 }

 public double getF1() {
     return f1;
 }

 public double getPrecison() {
     return precison;
 }

 public String getDate() {
     return date;
 }
 public double getRecall() {
     return recall;
 }
}
```

Here is the MSQL terminal outputting the columns for the entity created:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| f1       | double       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| precison | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| recall   | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is the class iam trying to add values to the database from:

```
@Controller
public class DataChart {

private static final Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataChart.class);

@Autowired
private static MeasurementRepository measurementRepository;

@GetMapping(value = "/statementchart")
@ResponseBody
public List<Measurement> scoreChartData() {

    List<MeasurementPoint> needDataPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MeasurementPoint> backgroundDataPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MeasurementPoint> goalDataPoints=new ArrayList<>();
    needDataPoints.add(new MeasurementPoint(0.3, 0.5, 0.2,  "2017-11-19"));
    needDataPoints.add(new MeasurementPoint(0.7, 0.4, 0.15, "2017-11-12"));
    needDataPoints.add(new MeasurementPoint(0.5, 0.3, 0.10, "2017-11-15"));
    needDataPoints.add(new MeasurementPoint(0.6, 0.2, 0.05, "2017-11-18"));
    measurementRepository.save(needDataPoints);

    backgroundDataPoints.add(new MeasurementPoint(0.2, 0.4, 0.2, "2017-11-19"));
    backgroundDataPoints.add(new MeasurementPoint(0.4, 0.3, 0.15, "2017-11-12"));
    measurementRepository.save(backgroundDataPoints);
   //backgroundDataPoints.add(new MeasurementPoint(0.5, 0.2, 0.10, "2017-11-15"));
   //measurementRepository.save(backgroundDataPoints);
```

Here is the output from saving these points:

```
+-----+------------+----------+--------+
| f1  | date       | precison | recall |
+-----+------------+----------+--------+
| 0.2 | 2017-11-19 |      0.4 |    0.2 |
| 0.3 | 2017-11-19 |      0.5 |    0.2 |
| 0.4 | 2017-11-12 |      0.3 |   0.15 |
| 0.5 | 2017-11-15 |      0.3 |    0.1 |
| 0.6 | 2017-11-18 |      0.2 |   0.05 |
| 0.7 | 2017-11-12 |      0.4 |   0.15 |
+-----+------------+----------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is my CrudRepository class:

```
public interface MeasurementRepository extends CrudRepository<MeasurementPoint,Long> {
}
```

**SOLVED**

saving these points works fine but as soon i save that out-commented new MeasurementPoint

```
//backgroundDataPoints.add(new MeasurementPoint(0.5, 0.2, 0.10, "2017-11-15"));
//measurementRepository.save(backgroundDataPoints);
```

i get a error saying: I guess it has to do with duplicate values but how do i fix this?

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session :
```

I solved it by creating a field of type long called id with annotation @Id because apparently every object created should get a unique id, the error thrown is because objects had some id. @GeneratedValue makes sure that everytime a new object is created a unqiue Id is given to that object.

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by removing @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
apparently and at the same time I was inserting id (any primary key value) by code too.
so the fix is: Do not insert id by code if using @GeneratedValue

Comment: Setting of Id manually shouldn't cause any problem if you are using `@GeneratedValue` Spring Data should handle this case, I think there is a bug in Spring Data `SimpleJpaRepository.save` method, can you please run you example with Id 3.0 instead of 0.3

Comment: @VitaliiMuzalevskyi you mean changing the datatype from double to integer in the crudrepository?

Comment: no, just change value in you example, I have some guess )

Comment: @VitaliiMuzalevskyi Ok so i changed new MeasurementPoint(3.0, 5.0, 2.0,  "2017-11-19") I get the error 

    org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: unrecognized id type : double -> java.lang.Double

but that is with the annotation:

    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)

If i remove that annotation it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think data is not saved because of errors. You just need to check logs. Enable [Hibernate SQL logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37464963/3405171) and check `insert` statement there.

1. You have `f1` as autogenerated column, but set value to it. Also I am not sure that `double` column can be autogenerated.
2. Hibernate needs a default constructor. `MeasurementPoint` doesn't have one.

This means `java.lang.NullPointerException: null(DataChart.java:30)`
that Spring doesn't set `measurementRepository` field. Try to remove the `static` modifier.

This  `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:` means that you shouldn't specify `f1` using the `save` method.

Comment: I added the eror message in the post at the bottom, it points to the measurementRepository.save method.

1) Iam setting the value to it? do you mean use a setter to set a value to it?
2) I added a default constructor, still not working.

Comment: @Genesis 1. No. Spring should set that value, because of Spring should generate code for the save method. 2. This error can happen in the future.

Comment: Now i get the error:

     org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:

which points at the measurementpoints class at that specific method

detached entity passed to persist: com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint

Comment: @Genesis You should provide a full stack trace of the error in the question. Probably better to ask another question for that.

Comment: check logs maybe something's wrong with accessing the database (check user permissions / password / that the db exists)

Comment: @v.ladynev do you mean that i shouldnt use save method at all?

Comment: @Genesis You can use it :) Looks like you already found a solution.

Comment: @v.ladynev Ye i did find a solution but i updated the post with a new error, check it out please

Comment: @v.ladynev The problem is that the repository interface dont have those methods... I can only do save i guess

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have this problem because you specified wrong ID type in you `CrudRepository`, your entity has ID of Double type but in repository is Long.

Edited:

Looks like `save` method of `JpaRepository` have some problems with double values, as I can see it always call `persist` method but it should call `merge` if Id is specified.

To solve this you can create your own Repository implementation where you will handle this.

Another solution is to change your Id type to Long if you have such possibility.

Comment: You mean you still get `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist`, or some other exception? Also add all stacktrace please.

Comment: I have added the stack trace in the post

Comment: Can you, please, try to change you Id value in your example to some integer number(to 3.0 instead of 0.3)

Comment: I changed the Id type to Long and the saving still works but not with duplicate values.

Comment: Update code in your post, to understand how it looks now