# how to update select column in Spring data?

Tags: spring, spring-data

Please check the below query I am trying to update a row by the composite key

my **key combination is like**:

```
int id  
int versionId
String languageId
```

**and query is**:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("update languageEntity l set l.language = :language where l.languageId = :languageId")

int UpdateProcessLanguage(@Param("language ") String processDesTranslation, @Param("languageId ") UserLanguageId languageId);
```

I am not getting any exception. function is returning `0`, means no row effected.

please check what is worng.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing the data. As a first step I would log the  generated SQL statements (see [how to log sql statements in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot)) and check if they look right.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont wan't to use save() method for that? Just change language property on your object and pass it to the save method. It will update the row.