# How to log Spring-data queries to a Couchbase Database

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, couchbase, sql++

In my `Spring-Boot` app we have a `Spring-Data` repository connection to the `Couchbase` server.

I know that when connecting to SQL server, one can see the actual queries sent to the DB by adding to the property file line such as this one ([As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot)):

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

What should be the way to do it when using Couchbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following deniswasrosa's answer I was able to see the queries just by adding this to the yml file:

```
logging:
   level:  
     org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query: DEBUG
```

I had no need to add the dependency.

Comment: Thanks, I will write a  post on Couchbase's blog about that to document this whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Add logback as your dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and add the file logback.xml to your resources folder:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

If I remember it correctly, you can enable dubug level only in the class that prints the query with the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query" level="debug" />

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm using Kotlin and `spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase` dependency, what it works for me on properties file was to use:

> logging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

I'm using spring data Couchbase 4.4.1 and had to use the below. Did not spend much time to find a better answer though. It workes for my porposes

```
<logger name="org.springframework.data.couchbase.core" level="trace" />
```