# Log Spring Data queries from reactive couchbase repository

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

a similar question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373431/how-to-log-spring-data-queries-to-a-couchbase-database). The solution is to set logging level from `org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query` to `DEBUG`:

```
logging:
   level:
     org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query: DEBUG
```

The difference in my case is that I'm using the reactive support and the bad boy above doesn't work. I also tried setting everything in `org.springframework.data` to DEBUG and still can't see any queries in the logs.

Mu guess is that there is something special about reactive repositories which I'm missing. Any ideas are more than welcome!

Comment: Have you tried logback (the answer bellow the accepted one)? I should work for you

Comment: I believe logback is used by default in spring boot - [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging)

`By default, if you use the “Starters”, Logback is used for logging. Appropriate Logback routing is also included to ensure that dependent libraries that use Java Util Logging, Commons Logging, Log4J, or SLF4J all work correctly`

Answer (score 1):

For reactive couchbase repository

Add the following to `application.yaml`

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.data.couchbase.core: TRACE
```

OR add the following to `logback.xml`

```
<logger name="org.springframework.data.couchbase.core" level="trace" />
```

And it will work from spring-data-couchbase:**4.3.2**

**Reference**

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1045