# JPA LAZY loading test case

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a contract entity which has oneToOne mapping with generatorState entity

I save one contract, it works and save the contract and the generatorState
However when I get the contract in Postman I have the details of the generatorState while I try to set it up as LAZY

Can someone please shed some lights on how to get the contract entity with/without the generatorState detailled

Main

```
     @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Contract c1 = new Contract (60,"TSTE");

//        GeneratorState gs = new GeneratorState(60,100);
//        c.setGeneratorState(gs);
//
//        contractRepository.save(c);
//        Contract c2 = contractRepository.findById(60).get();
//        System.out.println("coucou");
 
    }
```

Contract entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="contracts")
public class Contract {

    @Id
    int id;

    String symbol;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name ="id")
    private GeneratorState generatorState;

    public Contract(int id, String symbol) {
        this.id = id;
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    private ZonedDateTime createdOn;


    @JsonIgnore
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    private ZonedDateTime updatedOn;



}
```

GeneratorState

```
@Entity
@Table(name="state_generator")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GeneratorState {

    @Id
    int generatorId;

    public int getGeneratorId() {
        return generatorId;
    }

    public double getLastPrice() {
        return lastPrice;
    }

    double lastPrice;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "generatorState")
    Contract contract;

    public GeneratorState(int generatorId, double lastPrice) {
        this.generatorId = generatorId;
        this.lastPrice = lastPrice;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA Lazy loading is not working in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702642/jpa-lazy-loading-is-not-working-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 2):

from [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html), we find out that FetchType.LAZY means, that data CAN be lazily fetched.

It does not enforce that it will be lazily fetched, the decision when an entity is delivered as a whole is taken by the framework, and these decision usually make good sense.

Especially in your case, with a 1:1 relationship, the framework will deliver the entity expanded in most cases.

Easiest way to force it to be lazy is to make it 1:n. (not recommending that tho)

For more information look at [that blog](http://justonjava.blogspot.com/2010/09/lazy-one-to-one-and-one-to-many.html?_sm_au_=iVV024RFR7M6QSjrK82BvK0JskMpq)

There are some ways to force it to use Lazy loaded.

Also, this is maybe a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702642/jpa-lazy-loading-is-not-working-in-spring-boot)