# SQL statement not working while using with JPA Repository

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get records from `MYSQL` while posting a `GET` request from `POSTMEN`. The `SQL` query works in `MYSQL` console but not working in JPA Repository.

```
@Repository
public interface RecipeRepository extends JpaRepository<Recipe, Long> {
@Query(value = "select * from Recipe where Recipe.id in (select Recipe_id  
    from Recipe_keywords where keywords like '%:keyword_rec%') ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Recipe> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword_rec") String keyword_rec);
}
```

**Actual Result**

> No data selected

**Expected Result**

> A row is available in database which is being returned as a result of query while used with MYSQL console which should be returned here as well.

**Update**
by updating the query as suggested, no changes were made in the output.Here is the printed query

```
select * from Recipe r where r.id in (select rk.Recipe_id  from Recipe_keywords rk where rk.keywords like '%:keyword_rec%')
```

Comment: Set flag show sql to true and check the query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

Error was resolved changing my query to

```
select * from Recipe r where r.id in (select rk.Recipe_id  from Recipe_keywords rk where rk.keywords like %:keyword_rec%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the query you write on `MySQL` will be slightly different from the query you will write for `JPA`.

For example, `SELECT * FROM Customer becomes "SELECT c FROM Customer c"`

Have a look at the link:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html

Comment: No. He is issuing a native (SQL) query `nativeQuery = true`. Not a JPQL query.

Comment: You are totally right! I missed the natvieQuery attribute.