# Is there any way to maintain activity logs using spring boot and jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on admin panel of a project and i just want to log every activity same as in activity logs in facebook.

Comment: Yes you can do that. But you have to be a bit more precise what you want to do and what you want to log

Comment: I want to log each and every activity of admin e.g, every update ,delete and insert in tables

Comment: That's no problem. And what exactly to you want to know?

Comment: I think you can do something like this, as in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot

Comment: Initially I have created a table which is having fields like actionTakenOn and takenBy, but got stuck when it comes to the update api where i need to maintain the previous values, new value and field name also so that i can show that logs in user readable format. @SimonMartinelli

Comment: yes i can go in this way..but my concern is I want to show that logs to admin who is not technical , i just need them in user readable format and more specific @cipriancus

Comment: I already added a comment to you other question. Here you will find what you are looking for https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events

Answer (score 1):

Then I think what you can do is, you can create an advice on the methods that do the database work. Inside the advises check for user current permission ( e.g.: admin, I think it's in a principle and spring security gives this to you ) then you can create a message and write it in the table with the fields actionTakenOn and takenBy from where you can query and show the user.

I think this is quite a big feature, not sure if you will be able to get a complete answer with code examples.