# Spring enable SQL logs in application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, yaml

I'm building a spring boot application. I'm trying to enable SQL logs in application.yml. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log SQL statements in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use any one of these:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show_sql: true
```

or

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
    hibernate:
        sql:debug
        type:
        descriptor:
            sql:trace
```

Comment: Just quick correction:
`sql: debug` instead of `sql=debug`