# Hibernate JPA Many-to-Many Eager Loading not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_subscriptions",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Subscription> subscriptions;
}


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "subscriptions")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Subscription {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subscription")
    private Set<Notification> notifications;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subscriptions")
    private Set<User> users;
}


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "notifications")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Notification {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String message;
    @Column(name = "is_read", nullable = false)
    private boolean isRead;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id")
    private Subscription subscription;
}
```

I have created this 3 entities. User and Subscription have ManyToMany relationship. When I save user it works fine, in database I can see user`s subscriptions.

[image: user_subscriptions table]

When I call method findById to get user, I get subscriptions Set empty. How can I fix it?
I`m using Spring Boot v3.1.3, Java v17 and PostgreSQL v14.3

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues that could have been addressed here but were not. All the issues I have noticed.

- Suggested reading for fetch type `Eager`. [Hibernate many to many - fetch method eager vs lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150199/hibernate-many-to-many-fetch-method-eager-vs-lazy)
- Look at the SQL statements. Without that, you don't know what's actually going on. [Spring enable SQL logs in application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030522/spring-enable-sql-logs-in-application-yml)
- Lombok and JPA have issues. [Lombok and JPA: What Could Go Wrong?](https://dzone.com/articles/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong)
- You are using `Set` in your `Entities`. Bonus points for thinking about it but it can cause problems when the `List` is converted by JPA to a `Set`. You're better off not asking JPA to do anything extra if you can avoid it.
- You actually are eager fetching but the subscriptions are not included in your results.
- Assuming `Notification` is supposed to keep track of notifications to a specific `User`, your database schema does not accomplish that.

So, let's get started. If I create an example and execute a `findById` I get the following SQL.

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,s1_0.user_id,s1_1.id,s1_1.name,u1_0.username from users u1_0 left join (user_subscriptions s1_0 join subscriptions s1_1 on s1_1.id=s1_0.subscription_id) on u1_0.id=s1_0.user_id where u1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select n1_0.subscription_id,n1_0.id,n1_0.is_read,n1_0.message,n1_0.title from notifications n1_0 where n1_0.subscription_id=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.subscription_id,u1_1.id,u1_1.username from user_subscriptions u1_0 join users u1_1 on u1_1.id=u1_0.user_id where u1_0.subscription_id=?
Hibernate: select s1_0.user_id,s1_1.id,s1_1.name from user_subscriptions s1_0 join subscriptions s1_1 on s1_1.id=s1_0.subscription_id where s1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select n1_0.subscription_id,n1_0.id,n1_0.is_read,n1_0.message,n1_0.title from notifications n1_0 where n1_0.subscription_id=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.subscription_id,u1_1.id,u1_1.username from user_subscriptions u1_0 join users u1_1 on u1_1.id=u1_0.user_id where u1_0.subscription_id=?
```

Is this what you had in mind? I hope not. Let's fix it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscriptions")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Subscription {
```

Note that `@Data` has been removed and replaced with `@Getter` and `@Setter`. You could also have fixed it by using `List` instead of `Set`, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader to figure out why. Now my SQL is only the original first line.

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,s1_0.user_id,s1_1.id,s1_1.name,u1_0.username from users u1_0 left join (user_subscriptions s1_0 join subscriptions s1_1 on s1_1.id=s1_0.subscription_id) on u1_0.id=s1_0.user_id where u1_0.id=?
```

Note that you have joined the subscription table

```
left join (user_subscriptions s1_0 join subscriptions s1_1 on s1_1.id=s1_0.subscription_id)
```

but you have not included it for use in `User`.

```
select u1_0.id,s1_0.user_id,s1_1.id,s1_1.name,u1_0.username
```

Let's fix that.

```
@Query("from User u left join fetch u.subscriptions where u.id = :id")
Optional<User> findByIdWithSubscriptions(@Param("id") Long id);
```

This gives me

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,s1_0.user_id,s1_1.id,s1_1.name,u1_0.username from users u1_0 left join (user_subscriptions s1_0 join subscriptions s1_1 on s1_1.id=s1_0.subscription_id) on u1_0.id=s1_0.user_id where u1_0.id=?
User(id=1, username=un1, subscriptions=[Subscription(id=1, name=sub1), Subscription(id=2, name=sub2)])
```

This does not address `Notifications` but your question does not include that. Finally, let's get rid of the `Eager` since that's arguably a JPA-ANTIPATTERN. [JPA and Hibernate FetchType EAGER is a code smell](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) .

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_subscriptions",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Subscription> subscriptions;
```

And now we have a sensible `Repository` where `findById` gives us **only** the entity requested

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.username from users u1_0 where u1_0.id=?
```

and the method `findByIdWithSubscriptions` gives us the the joined subscriptions and includes them in the results.