# Entities are not loading correctly (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 entities, bookEntity and AuthorEntity, they have a ManyToMany relationship, when I create a record by sending a request (via postman), I get the expected result back, instead when I use the getBooks method, or getBookById the results are wrong, in the sense that apparently randomly no authors are shown.

## Entities

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "books")
public class BookEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "books_authors",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")}
    )
    private Set<AuthorEntity> authors;
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "authors")
public class AuthorEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Integer age;

    private Boolean dead;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<BookEntity> books;
}
```

## Book Controller and service

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<BookDTO> createBook(@RequestBody BookDTO bookDTO){
        BookEntity bookEntity;
        Set<AuthorEntity> authors = utilities.authorInsideBook(bookDTO);
        if(authors == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        bookEntity = bookMapper.mapFrom(bookDTO);
        bookEntity.setAuthors(authors);
        bookEntity = bookServiceImpl.save(bookEntity);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookMapper.mapTo(bookEntity), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<BookDTO> getBooks(){
        List<BookEntity> books = bookServiceImpl.getBooks();
        return books.stream().map(bookMapper::mapTo).toList();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<BookDTO> getBookById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id){
        Optional<BookEntity> bookEntity = bookServiceImpl.getBookById(id);
        return bookEntity.map(book -> {
            BookDTO bookDTO = bookMapper.mapTo(book);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(bookDTO, HttpStatus.FOUND);
        }).orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }


    @DeleteMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteBooksById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id){
        if(!bookServiceImpl.isExists(id)){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        bookServiceImpl.delete(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

```
    @Override
    public BookEntity save(BookEntity bookEntity) {
        return bookRepository.save(bookEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public List<BookEntity> getBooks() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(
                        bookRepository.findAll()
                                .spliterator(),
                        false)
                .toList();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<BookEntity> getBookById(Long id) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isExists(Long id) {
            return bookRepository.existsById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        bookRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoU9B.png)

Comment: Stop using Fetchtype.Eager on ManyToMany  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77683213/hibernate-jpa-many-to-many-eager-loading-not-working/77742838#77742838

Comment: Or better yet don't model ManyToMany relations. The Author doesn't need to reference the Book at all on entity-level. Just use an ManyToOne in the Book.