# Spring Boot - Tables are not being created automatically

Tags: sql, spring-boot

I am unable to get spring to create tables automatically. I tried every solution I could find regarding the properties and annotation that should be added.

Spring version - 5.2.5.RELEASE

My application properties looks like that:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ci_test?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
#management.server.port=8090
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
```

My Main app:

```
com.mypackage.autoTester;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.SpringVersion;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.mypackage.autoTester"})  // scan JPA entities
public class AutoTesterApplication {

    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AutoTesterApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

My Entity:

```
com.mypackage.autoTester.entities;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "testTable")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code above? Am I missing something?

UPDATE:

I tried the solutions below but no help :(
Back in the days I used spring boot plugin in eclipse and it worked, I now work with intellij so I am not sure if it is related

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `ddl-auto` to `create` instead of update in your `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Some of the values it accepts are:

`create`: creates the schema.

`update`: updates the schema.

`validate`: validates the schema.

`create-drop`: creates the schema and destroys the data previously present.

But this is not recommended for production databases, you can use [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) if you want incremental changes to be made to your db instead of hibernate `update`.

Comment: From what I understand here is when I need a new schema, I go to properties and change it to create, and then when I want to update it I need to change it to update again?

Comment: Also, it didn't work :( I am using Intellij if that makes any difference

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs of the app?

Comment: Nope, all looks good when I run the app. I see the Entity I created under the JPA persistence tool if that helps

Comment: I don't see any create statements but I added some more properties listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot and I saw some select statements on exiting tables, but no create statements

Answer (score 0):

try to add to your application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: are you sure your database "ci_test" exists  because you should create first in order to create the schema

Comment: Yes, I already have other tables configured

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and perhaps my question was lacking some information so it seems.

We are using 2 DBs and we initialize them manually in our code with the help of @EnableJpaRepositories

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager")
public class PrimaryConfig {
    private final Environment env;

    public PrimaryConfig(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name")));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                primaryEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("");

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true); // -> added this line 
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return em;
    }
}
```

So I needed to add only one line for it to work and start executing the SQL commands automatically.

It appears that since we created it manually, the properties added to the application.properties file didn't make any difference, or at least some of them.

I hope it will help other people who see this also since I wasted a lot of time on this :)