# ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = bigint

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, internal-server-error

I have an error regarding deploying the backend trough docker on localhost 8080 .

When i run the website normally (started the postgres server from inteliji) it works properly.

When i try to deploy it trough docker i get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = bigint
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 580
```

The next code is an example of class using UUID

```
package com.ds.assignment1.ds2021_30244_rusu_vlad_assignment_1.entity;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Data
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid4")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid4", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;
}
```

Comment: The error message is explicit : your sql code tries to test an equality between a data of type uuid and a data of type bigint, which is not allowed. You have to correct your sql code or display it if you need any help.

Comment: i kow this is the problem ,i dont know how to solve it because i worked with jpa so i didnt write any specific queries.

Comment: The error points at position 580 of your code. Diffiult to help if yo can't share the code.

Comment: Check the schema of your postgres database table, I guess the `id` column of your table is of type bigint.

Comment: i checked and the data type is uuid

Comment: The issue is that in whatever query is executing at line 580 is doing something like: `id = <some_parameter>` where `<some_parameter>` is an `integer`. You will need to track down why is being assigned an `integer`?

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that the `database column is UUID` whereas the `JPA entity is bigint`. **I should mention that this may be or may not be about the ID field of this entity.**

As @Adrian-klaver said you have to look at position 580 of the SQL query, which you can do by [enabling hibernate query logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-can-i-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot) and looking at the last hibernate SQL query log.

I had a similar problem, spending three days to finally resolve it. My problem was due to having multiple attribute types being different than their database type. As I was migrating from `Long id` to `UUID`, it made me confuse figuring out what the cause for my error was.

Comment: Dear @StenTechy This is not an easy fix. Please enable logging and dig carefully to find the exact lines responsible for the error.