# How to set show-sql to true once the Spring Boot Application has been started

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, show-sql

How to set show-sql to true once the Spring Boot Application has been started

We start application with `spring.jpa.show-sql=false` in `src/main/resources/application.properties`

If we need to momentarily turn on show-sql, how should we do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I log SQL statements in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-can-i-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Also, [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#conditional) supports conditionals. You might be able to dynamically set a variable there that is then properly evaluated.

Comment: Its not the same, since I am asking how to manage it once the application is up and running without restarting the App

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60289026/7109162) includes solutions which might be possible to be adjusted to your needs. Also logbacks conditionals might be able to do what you need with `<configuration scan="true">` to periodically reload the configuration

Comment: The App is running inside a docker container, so it wouldn't be possible to modify or reload the file. How else to start or stop logging of the SQL

Comment: Did you even read the answer I linked? There is no easy on the fly solution I am aware of. You need to implement a solution yourself, so start doing some research