# Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA: does not appear the Binding Parameters for JPA/Hibernate queries in the terminal

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

For `Spring Boot` **3.1.1** working with `Spring Data JPA` and others as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And taking in consideration the following tutorials and SO post respectively:

- [Show Hibernate/JPA SQL Statements from Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot)
- [Show SQL from Spring Data JPA/hibernate in Spring Boot](https://springhow.com/spring-boot-show-sql/)
- [How can I log SQL statements in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-can-i-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot)

Therefore having the `application.properties` file as follows:

```
spring.profiles.active=h2

#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

If is executed any of the following commands:

- `mvn spring-boot:run`
- `mvn test -Dtest=com.manuel.jordan.service.crud.CienciaServiceCrudTests`

In the terminal appears the SQL queries for all the CRUD methods as expected, therefore insert, update, delete etc ..., but does **not** appear the *binding parameters* as expected as the links (2nd and 3rd) have reported through their outputs. Therefore if is opened the dialog window to search, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> on Ubuntu terminal, by using the search keys for either `bind` and `parameter` there are no coincidences.

Something special missing? or something to update? it about the *Application Properties*

Was tried with:

```
spring.profiles.active=h2

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

and

```
spring.profiles.active=h2

#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

and nothing

Just in case, it happens if the profile is changed from *h2* to *mysql*